# MySQL combine two columns and list all doubles on those columns

Tags: mysql, concatenation

I have trouble using CONCAT in a query where I combine the first and last name of people and then finding other records with the same first and last name.

(I want to put all found id's in an PHP array for later use.)

**THE PROBLEM**

I can't seem to skip the GROUP BY. The query gives a correct count of the doubles found, but I need all the seperate records (the id's + other fields).
MySQL says I can't use 'fullname' because it isn't a column. I get that, but that combination is what I am searching for.

When using other queries, I keep getting results where it lists doubles on both first and last name - where I want it on the CONCAT fullname.

**THE CODE**

```
SELECT 
    id,firstname,lastname,artistname, CONCAT(firstname,' ', lastname) as fullname, COUNT(lastname)
FROM
    table
GROUP BY 
    fullname
HAVING 
       (COUNT(lastname) > 1)
```

So, the code works, but I'd like to have all the seperate records listed.

Any help in getting me on the right path here is highly appreciated.

Comment: Your query `group by` is invalid for standard SQL, see [mysql_only_full_group_by](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by), however you can just repeat the `CONCAT(firstname,' ', lastname)` in the `group by`

Comment: Good info, but it still does not select only the ones with the same first- and last name. It gives results on the same lastname now.

Comment: Add some sample data and desired results to your question. If you're using MySql 8+ you could use `count() over a window`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
SELECT A.id, A.firstname, A.lastname, A.artistname,
       CONCAT(A.firstname,' ', A.lastname) AS fullname, cnt
FROM mytable A
JOIN
(SELECT 
    firstname, lastname, COUNT(lastname) cnt
FROM
    mytable
GROUP BY firstname,lastname) B
 ON A.firstname=B.firstname 
 AND A.lastname=B.lastname
WHERE cnt > 1
```

Modify your attempted query to become a subquery then join the table with it. Matching condition on `firstname` and `lastname` then add `WHERE cnt > 1` to get match only those having count more than one.

Or perhaps, if you're on MySQL v8 (or MariaDB that supports window function), then consider this method:

```
SELECT * 
 FROM
(SELECT 
     id, firstname, lastname, CONCAT(firstname,' ', lastname) AS fullname,
     COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY firstname, lastname) cnt
 FROM mytable) V
 WHERE cnt > 1
```

Using `COUNT() OVER ()` window function then make it as a subquery. Note that you can't use `HAVING cnt > 1` directly on the query as it will return you error

> Error 3594: You cannot use the alias 'cnt' of an expression containing a window function in this context.'

so the subquery is necessary.

[Demo fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=bc59673d7a7e03cf90d22253f583ef8f)

Comment: This: 'Modify your attempted query to become a subquery[...]' is probably the best explanation I've seen explaining the use of subqueries. Thank you so much! This totally does what I needed. I only had to leave out some empty fields and add the order.